# Calculating satisfaction scores when some months aren't reported

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have this table (Postgres 9.5) composed of a interation id, a satisfaction value (1 for satisfied 0 for not satisfied), and the date of the interaction that is truncated to the first day of the month in which it took place. Assume that the layout of this table cannot be changed.

```
interaction | satisfaction  | surveyed_on
------------+---------------+-------------
     325524 |             1 | 2016-01-01
     325999 |             1 | 2016-01-01
     332642 |             0 | 2016-03-01
     333152 |             1 | 2016-02-01
     326765 |             0 | 2016-01-01
```

How would I calculate satisfaction percentage on a monthly basis while accounting for the fact that it's possible for some months to not receive positive or negative interactions which. Ideally, the results would look something like this:

```
  month     | positive_scr  | negative_scr | satisfaction_pct
------------+---------------+--------------+-----------------
 2016-01-01 |           100 |            1 |              99
 2016-02-01 |            10 |            5 |              50
 2016-03-01 |            50 |           10 |              80
 2016-04-01 |            35 |           35 |             100
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please mention the database name/version also

Comment: @Utsav Apologies, thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach this using a couple of steps:

1. Generate a date series (in the attached example I have used the postgres generate_series function).  This allows you calculate scores for months where limited data is available
2. Join your data on to this date series
3. Aggregate your data, transposing your positive/negative scores into their own columns

I've had a go in the attached [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bce0a/11):

```
select  dt,
        sum( case when satisfaction = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as positive_scr,
        sum( case when satisfaction = 0 then 1 else 0 end ) as negative_scr,
        sum( case when satisfaction = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) * 100 / count(*) as satisfaction_pct
from    (
          /* If not using Postgres you will need to use your database specific function here */
          select  generate_series( '2016-01-01', '2016-04-01', interval '1 month' ) as dt
        ) as a
        left join
        (
          select  satisfaction, surveyed_on
          from    scores
        ) as b
        on a.dt = b.surveyed_on
 group by dt
```

Comment: You probably need `a.dt::date` in the join condition because `generate_series()` returns timestamps, not dates

Comment: `generate_series`, good stuff! This was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this kind of query, which will work on almost all popular RDBMS.

Note: You have to handle `divide by 0` condition while handling `percentage`, but that would be database specific, so I left it for you to figure out.

The formula I am using to calculate `satisfaction percentage` is `100 - negative_score*(100/positive_score)`. If you want to change it, just put `negative_score` and `positive score` on your custom formula.

<kbd>**[`Rextester Demo`](http://rextester.com/LJTP92557)**</kbd>

```
select 
surveyed_on,
sum(case when satisfaction=1 then 1 else 0 end) as positive , 
sum(case when satisfaction=0 then 1 else 0 end) as negative ,
(100 - (sum(case when satisfaction=0 then 1 else 0 end))
         *(100/(sum(case when satisfaction=1 then 1 else 0 end)))
) as satisfaction_percent
from tbl234
group by surveyed_on;
```